# Dekker's method for numerical analysis not converging correctly

Tags: python, numerical-methods, root-finding

I am trying to implement Dekker's method for root finding and I can't seem to figure out an issue where the algorithm does not seem to correctly converge to a solution and stops abruptly sometimes.

My implementation is based on the equations on the Wiki for Dekker's method [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method)

I'm quite new to python and programming and would appreciate any insight into where I might be going wrong.

```
def dekker(func, x_bounds, tolerance, max_iterations):
    # Initial bounds
    a0, b0 = x_bounds
    bk = b0
    b_minus_1 = a0 # previous bk but start with a
    
    k = 0

    print(' k xk        f(xk)')

    while k < max_iterations:
        fk = eval(fnon)(bk)
        f_minus_1 = eval(func)(b_minus_1)

        # check for division by zero when attemping secant method
        if fk - f_minus_1 == 0:
            # implement bisection method when division by zero 
            bk_plus_1 = (a0 + bk) / 2
        else:
            sk = bk - (bk - b_minus_1) / (fk - f_minus_1) * fk #secant
            mk = (a0 + bk) / 2 # bisection 
            
            if sk >= mk and sk <= bk:
                bk_plus_1 = sk
            else:
                bk_plus_1 = mk

        fk_plus_1 = eval(func)(bk_plus_1)

        if fk * fk_plus_1 < 0:
            a_k_plus_1 = bk
            b_k_plus_1 = bk_plus_1
        else:
            a_k_plus_1 = a0
            b_k_plus_1 = bk_plus_1

        if abs(eval(func)(a_k_plus_1)) < abs(eval(func)(b_k_plus_1)):
            best_solution = a_k_plus_1
        else:
            best_solution = b_k_plus_1

        k += 1
        print('{0:2.0f}  {1:2.8f}  {2:2.2e}'.format(k, bk_plus_1, abs(fk_plus_1)))

        if(abs(bk - b_minus_1) < tolerance):
            print('Converged')
            break

        bk = bk_plus_1
        b_minus_1 = bk

    if k == max_iterations:
        print('Not converged')
```

Testing method:

```
def function(x):
    return -np.cos(x) + x*x*x + 2*x*x + 1
dekker('function', [-3,1], 1e-6, 100)
```

Comment: Note you can avoid the evals by passing the actual function name, i.e., `dekker(function, [-3, 1], 1e-6, 100)`

Comment: You have fixed the fnon/func problem with your latest edit, but you haven't fixed the convergence criteria.  You also need to change `maxk` to `max_iterations`.

Comment: I would also suggest preforming your initial testing on an even more obvious correct answer.

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks for letting me know. Updated that too. What might be a good test to check for convergence? Is the rest of the implementation fine?

Comment: Well I tried `return x*x - 4`, which should have roots at -2 and 2.  Unfortunately, the code with the suggested changes and given the interval [1, 3] converges to `xk == 1`.  So besides the initial typo issues, there does appear to be a problem with your implementation.

Comment: At least problem appears to be that you are setting `a_k_plus_1` back to `a0`.

Comment: I was able to morph your code into a working version.  You need to fix your initialization and end-of-loop reinitialization.  You need to initialize an `ak` value and update it with `ak_plus_1` at the end of each loop, and use that variable instead of `a0` in the calculations.  You also need to reverse the order of your `bk = bk_plus_1` and `bk_minus_1 = bk` lines.  With the order your specify, the first assignment overwrites the value that you want to save into `b_minus_1`.  I would also be a bit more consistent with your variable naming.  It will eliminate a lot of problems.

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks for the reply! would you mind posting an answer of the changes so I can better understand? still slightly confused. Would also help me accept the answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You had a number of problems.

First, you were only computing`mk` when you used the bisection method.  You need to compute `mk` on EVERY iteration, because you need to compare `sk` and `mk` every time.

Next, your two lines of code to advance `bk` and `bk_plus_1` at the end were not in the right order, so you trashed the `bk` value before saving it.

Next, you were doing the computation to check whether you needed to move `ak`, but you never used the results of that computation.  This seems to work:

```
import numpy as np

def dekker(func, x_bounds, tolerance, max_iterations):
    ak, bk = x_bounds
    b_minus_1 = ak # previous bk but start with a
    
    print(' k xk        f(xk)')

    for k in range(max_iterations):
        fk = func(bk)
        f_minus_1 = func(b_minus_1)

        # check for division by zero when attempting secant method

        mk = (ak + bk) / 2 # bisection 
        if fk == f_minus_1:
            bk_plus_1 = mk
        else:
            sk = bk - (bk - b_minus_1) / (fk - f_minus_1) * fk #secant
            
            if mk <= sk <= bk or bk <= sk <= mk:
                bk_plus_1 = sk
            else:
                bk_plus_1 = mk

        fk_plus_1 = func(bk_plus_1)

        b_minus_1 = bk

        if fk * fk_plus_1 < 0:
            ak = bk

        bk = bk_plus_1

        if abs(func(ak)) < abs(func(bk)):
            best_solution = ak
        else:
            best_solution = bk

        print('{0:2.0f}  {1:2.8f}  {2:2.2e}'.format(k, bk_plus_1, abs(fk_plus_1)), best_solution)

        if(abs(fk - fk_plus_1) < tolerance):
            print('Converged', bk)
            return bk

    print('Not converged')
    return None


def function(x):
    return -np.cos(x) + x*x*x + 2*x*x + 1

def plotme():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x = np.arange( -3, 1, .01 )
    y = function(x)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()

#plotme()
print(dekker(function, [-3,1], 1e-6, 100))
```

Output:

```
 k xk        f(xk)
 0  -0.32179374  2.25e-01 -0.3217937387377827
 1  -0.41378380  3.56e-01 -0.41378379538544446
 2  -1.70689190  1.99e+00 -1.7068918976927223
 3  -2.35344595  2.52e-01 -2.3534459488463613
 4  -2.28064072  1.92e-01 -2.280640719265942
 5  -2.31209175  6.87e-03 -2.3120917484530077
 6  -2.31325946  2.00e-04 -2.313259456426466
 7  -2.31322651  1.97e-07 -2.313226508522713
 8  -2.31322654  5.65e-12 -2.313226541057924
Converged -2.313226541057924
-2.313226541057924
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version.

```
def dekker(fnon, x_bounds, tolerance, max_iterations):
    # Initial bounds
    a0, b0 = x_bounds
    ak = a0
    bk = b0
    bk_minus_1 = a0 # previous bk but start with a
    
    k = 0

    print(' k xk        f(xk)')

    while k < max_iterations:
        fk = fnon(bk)
        fk_minus_1 = fnon(bk_minus_1)

        # check for division by zero when attemping secant method
        if fk - fk_minus_1 == 0:
            # implement bisection method when division by zero 
            bk_plus_1 = (a0 + bk) / 2
        else:
            sk = bk - (bk - bk_minus_1) / (fk - fk_minus_1) * fk #secant
            mk = (a0 + bk) / 2 # bisection 

            if sk >= mk and sk <= bk:
                bk_plus_1 = sk
            else:
                bk_plus_1 = mk

        fk_plus_1 = fnon(bk_plus_1)

        if fk * fk_plus_1 < 0:
            ak_plus_1 = bk
            bk_plus_1 = bk_plus_1
        else:
            ak_plus_1 = ak
            bk_plus_1 = bk_plus_1

        if abs(fnon(ak_plus_1)) < abs(fnon(bk_plus_1)):
            best_solution = ak_plus_1
        else:
            best_solution = bk_plus_1

        print('{0:2.0f}  {1:2.8f}  {2:2.2e}'.format(k, bk_plus_1, abs(fk_plus_1)))

        if(abs(bk - bk_plus_1) < tolerance):
            print('Converged')
            break

        bk_minus_1 = bk
        bk = bk_plus_1
        ak = ak_plus_1
        k += 1

    if k == max_iterations:
        print('Not converged')
```

And some validation

```
def f2(x):
    return x*x - 4
dekker(f2, [1,4], 1e-6, 100)
```

prints

```
 k xk        f(xk)
 1  2.50000000  2.25e+00
 2  2.15384615  6.39e-01
 3  2.01652893  6.64e-02
 4  2.00060976  2.44e-03
 5  2.00000251  1.00e-05
 6  2.00000000  1.53e-09
 7  2.00000000  1.78e-15
Converged
```

There were a number of issues not previously mentioned, but one important problem is your reinitialization at the end of the loop.  If you set `bk = bk_plus_1` and then `bk_minus_1 = bk` then you have actually set `bk_minus_1` equal to `bk_plus_1` as well and lost the value of `bk` that you wanted to set `bk_minus_1` equal to.  You haven't updated `ak` from your calculated `ak_plus_1`.

There are a number of further improvements you might consider.  For example, you should have the method return the `xk` value you have found.  That way the results of your function can be used in further calculations.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought I had hit post on this hours ago.  Meanwhile Tim Roberts solution includes some of the further improvements I allude to.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sources

There are several sources for what Dekker's algorithm could be. I use the variant referenced in

- [Cleve Moler (2015), *"Zeroin, Part 1, Dekker's Algorithm](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/10/12/zeroin-part-1-dekkers-algorithm/)

which uses the algorithm from

- T. J. Dekker and W. Hoffmann (1968), *"Algol 60 Procedures in Numerical Algebra"*

and also cites a conference report

- Dekker (1969), *"Finding a zero by means of successive linear interpolation"*

The root-finding algorithm there that mixes of secant and bisection steps is also discussed as algorithm A in

- Bus, Dekker (1975), *"Two Efficient Algorithms with Guaranteed
  Convergence for Finding a Zero of a Function"*

The main thrust of that article is to discuss modifications of the basic idea using roots of non-linear approximations of the function as iteration points.

Wikipedia's Brent article only refers to the conference report Dekker (1969) and other reviews from the perspective of the Brent algorithm. So for Dekker alone it is a dubious source, as both sources are likely to have simplified the algorithm to its basic idea.

#### The algorithm

In extension of the bisection and other bracketing methods, the state of Dekkers method has 3 points *a,b,c*. Their functions are that from *a,b* the next secant root is computed and *[b,c]* is a bracketing interval, that is, the values at *b,c* have a different sign, ensuring the presence of a root in the interval. Additionally, *b* is the "best" point, has the smallest function value among the three points. The algorithm enforces that the new point is inside *[b,c]* closer to *b*.

At the start of the method, the interval *[a,b]* is given and extended to a "triangle" *[a,b,c] = [a,b,a]*. The points get sorted so that *b* has the smaller value. After selecting the next point *v* inside *[b,c]*, the secant sequence get shifted to * a,b = b,v*. Then the new bracketing interval gets selected. The sign sequence of the values at the new *a,b,c* has one alternation. If it is again between *b* and *c*, nothing needs to be done, the sequence *a,b,c* remains "linear". Otherwise the alternation is between *a* and *b*, so set *c=a* as the new counter-point.

The midpoint selection has 3 variants:

- In "secant" mode, the secant root *v=s* is inside of the bracketing interval, moreover between the midpoint *m* and *b*. In the majority of situations, the value at *s* has the same sign as the value at *b* and a significantly smaller size, so that the other interval end *c* remains unchanged and the secant root sequence can be continued without break, *a,b = b,s*. A sign change between the values at *b* and *v=s* is less likely, but still quite possible.
- In "midpoint" mode it was detected that the secant root sequence diverges from the bracketing interval, either falling outside or making an unexpected large step away from *b* to the other side of *m*. In this case it is more likely that the value of the midpoint is not smaller than the previous values, or that the sign changes between the values at *b* and *v=m*
- a "minimal" step is performed to resolve numerically ambiguous situations. For instance if the secant root sequence converges to step sizes below the tolerances, one or several minimal steps are used to also shrink the bracketing interval to this minimal size. At convergence at a multiple root where there is no sign change, which is numerically ambiguous, one or more minimal steps will move this root outside the bracketing interval and restart the search for a root with a sign change.

#### Applied to the test problem

The trace of the Dekker method for this equation should look like

```
a=x[-1], b=x[-1], c=x[-1] -> initial   : x[ 0] =  -3.000000000000000,  f(x[ 0]) =  -7.010007503399553
a=x[ 0], b=x[-1], c=x[-1] -> initial   : x[ 1] =   1.000000000000000,  f(x[ 1]) =   3.459697694131860
a=x[ 0], b=x[ 1], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 2] =  -0.321793738737783,  f(x[ 2]) =   0.225110648393170
a=x[ 1], b=x[ 2], c=x[ 0] -> secant    : x[ 3] =  -0.413783795385445,  f(x[ 3]) =   0.355981221390157
a=x[ 2], b=x[ 3], c=x[ 0] -> midpoint  : x[ 4] =  -1.706891897692722,  f(x[ 4]) =   1.989640412053239
a=x[ 3], b=x[ 4], c=x[ 0] -> midpoint  : x[ 5] =  -2.353445948846361,  f(x[ 5]) =  -0.252473245321568
a=x[ 4], b=x[ 5], c=x[ 4] -> secant    : x[ 6] =  -2.280640719265942,  f(x[ 6]) =   0.192012983736426
a=x[ 5], b=x[ 6], c=x[ 5] -> secant    : x[ 7] =  -2.312091748453008,  f(x[ 7]) =   0.006873812772492
a=x[ 6], b=x[ 7], c=x[ 5] -> secant    : x[ 8] =  -2.313259456426466,  f(x[ 8]) =  -0.000199582032968
a=x[ 7], b=x[ 8], c=x[ 7] -> secant    : x[ 9] =  -2.313226508522713,  f(x[ 9]) =   0.000000197276950
a=x[ 8], b=x[ 9], c=x[ 8] -> secant    : x[10] =  -2.313226541057924,  f(x[10]) =   0.000000000005652
a=x[ 9], b=x[10], c=x[ 8] -> minimal   : x[11] =  -2.313226541058924,  f(x[11]) =  -0.000000000000412
exit by interval length
a=x[10], b=x[11], c=x[10] -> best value: x[11] =  -2.313226541058924,  f(x[11]) =  -0.000000000000412
```

The use of `a,b,c` is taken from the Dekker/Bus paper. Here `c` is the counter-point with value of opposite sign to the current best point `b`, and `a` is usually the former best point if the last step was a secant step.

Note the regular sign switch in the function value which indicates a substantial shrinking of the bracketing interval `[b,c]`.

---

The code, with all the facilities to print out the trace of the algorithm, is

```
from math import sin, cos, exp

def dekker(f_in, a, b, tol=1e-7):
    mode = "initial"
    A=B=C=None
    
    class Point(object):
        k=0
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
            self.k = Point.k
            self.f = f_in(x); 
            a_str = "       " if not A else f"a=x[{A.k:2d}]"
            b_str = "       " if not B else f"b=x[{B.k:2d}]"
            c_str = "       " if not C else f"c=x[{C.k:2d}]"
            print(f"{a_str}, {b_str}, {c_str} -> {mode:10s}:", end='')
            print(f" x[{self.k:2d}] = {self.x:19.15f},  f(x[{self.k:2d}]) = {self.f:19.15f}"); 
            Point.k+=1; 
 
    A = Point(a)
    B = Point(b)
    if A.f*B.f > 0: 
        error("need sign change in initial interval")
    # [a,b] is bracketing interval, establish triangle formation, [b,c] now also bracketing
    C = A
    while 1>0:
        # make b the best. In superlinear mode nothing should happen here
        if abs(C.f) < abs(B.f): 
            A, B, C = B, C, B    # triangle formation
        # atomic step size
        db = tol
        if abs(C.x-B.x)<2*db: print("exit by interval length"); break
        # minimal change in case of stalling
        h = B.x + (db if C.x>B.x else -db);
        # elements of the secant step
        p = B.f*(A.x-B.x); q = (B.f-A.f);
        if p<0: p,q = -p,-q
        # default for midpoint step
        v = m = 0.5*(B.x+C.x); mode = "midpoint"
        # secant step if step update is large enough
        if p > abs(db*q):
            s = B.x+p/q
            # step goes not beyond midpoint, else remain at midpoint
            if p < q*(v-B.x): v = s; mode = "secant"
        else: v=h; mode = "minimal"
        # shift the secant sequence
        A, B = B, Point(v);
        # Now a < b=v <= m < c or in the other direction. Between a and c there is a sign change
        # If the sign also changes between b and c, do nothing, linear formation remains.
        # Else copy a to c, establishing a triangle formation
        if B.f*C.f > 0:
            C = A
        # Now [b,c] is ensured to be bracketing and (a,b) is ready for the next secant root computation
    mode = "best value"
    Point.k = B.k; Point(B.x);    # this is just for some nice printing
    return B.x, C.x
        
dekker(lambda x: -cos(x) + x*x*x + 2*x*x + 1, -3, 1, tol=1e-12)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you happen to have the code which achieved this? Your one seems to converge quite differently and more quickly than mine. Would be nice to compare.